# Force ggplot2 to use the same labels and colors on the legends for two plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to create several plots with ggplot2, and I'd like it to assign always the same color to the each factor type.

Here you have a toy example.

```
mydata <- data.frame(from=rep(c("b","c"), each=15),
    to=rep(c("a","b","c"), each=10), 
    value=c(rep(1:5,5:1),rep(1:5,1:5)) )
```

I first convert the categories to factors in order to assign always the same value and because it worked on other plots I did.

I want to create two density plots (or similar) from the value grouped by categories in two ways, one using the categories of the "from" column, another one with the categories of the "to" column, using the same legend.

```
niv <- c("a", "b", "c")
colo <- c("black", "red", "blue")

mydata$from <- factor(mydata$from, levels=niv)
mydata$to <- factor(mydata$to, levels=niv)
```

And now I generate the plots.
First with grouping by the "from" column.

```
ggplot(mydata) +  stat_density(geom="line",size=0.8,
 position = "identity", aes(x=value, color=from)) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Type",labels = niv, 
  values=colo)  +  theme_bw()
```

[image]

As you can see it doesn't produce the desired plot because it shows an "a" factor but it doesn't exist on the "from" column.

And now grouping by the "to" column.

```
ggplot(mydata) +  stat_density(geom="line",size=0.8,
  position = "identity", aes(x=value, color=to)) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Type",labels = niv, 
  values=colo)  +  theme_bw()
```

[image]

It works as expected.

Now I try to produce again the first plot without the labels parameter.

```
ggplot(mydata) +  stat_density(geom="line",size=0.8,
  position = "identity", aes(x=value, color=from)) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Type", values=colo)  +  
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Now it labels properly the categories but the color don't match with the second plot.

How can I do it?

The real problem has more categories and many values.

Comment: The `scale_*` functions generally have a `drop` argument for whether unused levels will be shown in the corresponding legend. It defaults to true, so try setting it to false

Comment: In my real example there are a many unused factors and then the legend is too big. The plot is generated filtering out some levels.

Comment: So could you drop the levels you don't want in the plot (`forcats::fct_drop` is a convenient way), then set your scale to not drop the remaining ones that you *do* want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a named vector in `scale_color_manual` to map `Type` explicitly to colors:

```
color_map <- c("a" = "black", "b" = "red", "c" = "blue")
scale_colour_manual(values=color_map)
```

From the `help(scale_color_manual)`:

> values
>
> a set of aesthetic values to map data values to. If this is a
>   named vector, then the values will be matched based on the names. If
>   unnamed, values will be matched in order (usually alphabetical) with
>   the limits of the scale. Any data values that don't match will be
>   given na.value.

Here is the full code that, I believe, produces the output that you want:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydata <- data.frame(
  from = rep(c("b", "c"), each = 15),
  to = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 10),
  value = c(rep(1:5, 5:1), rep(1:5, 1:5))
)

niv <- c("a", "b", "c")
colo <- c("black", "red", "blue")

color_map <- set_names(colo, niv)

mydata$from <- factor(mydata$from, levels = niv)
mydata$to <- factor(mydata$to, levels = niv)

ggplot(mydata) + stat_density(
  geom = "line", size = 0.8,
  position = "identity", aes(x = value, color = from)
) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Type", values = color_map) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(mydata) + stat_density(
  geom = "line", size = 0.8,
  position = "identity", aes(x = value, color = to)
) +
  scale_colour_manual(
    name = "Type",
    values = color_map
  ) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I'll try, thanks. I thought it was the same I was doing. Do you suggest also explicitly converting the column to factors before?  How can I automatically create this mapped vector from my "niv" and "colo" vectors?

Comment: It's interesting though it has a problem, the factor not used on my plot (but exist on my niv list" appear on the legend as NA if i use drop=F.  If I used drop=T instead then it desn't preserve the explicit relations I've created.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, I don't get NA in the plot where the `a` level is not present. I posted the full code above, is that your expected behavior?

Comment: Oh and to make the named vector without typing it all out, I would use the [set_names](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/set_names.html) function, like in the example above.